# Angular 4 global variable setting issue

Tags: angular, typescript, global-variables

I'm trying to set global variable in my `LoginService` so I can inject it to my `DriverService`. However, no matter how I implement the global variable, it's always either `undefined` or empty string.

I made a plunker, so you can check it live: [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/LSj6PijH0nfRyJNA1FzX?p=preview)

I tried with setValue (`this.login = value`) and getValue(`return this.login`) things, now I tried with Subject and BehaviorSubject, but with no success.

How can I set my global variable in one service, so I can use it in another service?

Thanks

Comment: do you want the true global variable on global object that can be accessed in a console?

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly, but I want a global variable that it's value would be accessible in other services. I use console here just to check if my code even returns what I want it to.

Comment: DriverService constructor is not called in your plunker

Comment: well, `DriverService` constructor is still not called

Comment: Um, how do I call service `constructor`? I though when I use `DriverService` instance, the constructor would be called.

Comment: yes, but at the moment it's probably not used since if I put debugger in the constructor it's not paused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have to remember with Services (Injectables in general), is that if you want the same instance of service in your app, you need to add them to `providers` array in your `NgModule`, which will make the same instance of service available for all components that are in that module. In this case you of course want exactly that!

Having `providers`-array in each component, means that all your components will have their own instance of the service(s), so that means they are not sharing the same data at all.

So the only thing needed was to remove the `providers` arrays from the components, and instead apply them in your `NgModule` :)

Your fixed **[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/DIFded57QaU0MYLKXyO4?p=preview)**.